# WCF to Java endpoint/contract issue

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-interoperability

Getting error with Could not find endpoint element with name 'CaseJacketPort' and contract 'GrandJuryService.CaseJacket'

```
private void InitProxy()
{
    m_Proxy = new DivisionAssignmentJSS.GrandJuryService.CaseJacketClient("CaseJacketPort");  << error here
```

From my App.config:

```
<client>
   <endpoint address="http://172.24.8.125:8080/grandjury/CaseJacketService"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CaseJacketPortBinding1"
        contract="GrandJuryService.CaseJacket" name="CaseJacketPort" />
</client>
```

as well as

```
<binding name="CaseJacketPortBinding1">
  <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128" 
            authenticationMode="UserNameForCertificate"
            requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Strict" 
            includeTimestamp="true" keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" 
                messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10" requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
        <localClientSettings cacheCookies="true" detectReplays="true"
          replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00" maxCookieCachingTime="Infinite"
          replayWindow="00:05:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10:00:00"
          sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="true"
          timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" cookieRenewalThresholdPercentage="60" />
        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" issuedCookieLifetime="10:00:00"
          maxStatefulNegotiations="128" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00"
          negotiationTimeout="00:01:00" replayWindow="00:05:00" inactivityTimeout="00:02:00"
          sessionKeyRenewalInterval="15:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00"
          reconnectTransportOnFailure="true" maxPendingSessions="128"
          maxCachedCookies="1000" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" />
        <secureConversationBootstrap />
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding 
             maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
             messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" writeEncoding="utf-8">
          <readerQuotas 
                 maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                 maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport 
            manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" allowCookies="false" 
            authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="6553600" 
            proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" 
            transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    </binding>
```

No idea why they cannot see each other?
The error says "This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, 
or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element."

when i ^F and search for the pointer they look to all point to one another.

Any ideas?

TIA

__Stephen

Comment: @SteveO: you need to highlight your code and config sections and then click on the "code" button (010 101) in the toolbar or press Ctrl-K on your keyboard to make them be properly visible and nicely formatted / syntax-highlighted

Comment: Just a wild guess but are you using an app.config in a web application? Or perhaps a app.config with a library where only the applications config file is read?

Comment: Using an app.config to hold the endpoint and binding data.  

Otherwise app will act more like a service dll for other projects as needed.  We use to have our own data wrapper to pull this data and now customer wants a their team to make a secure WS to log all requests through.  this is my first go at communication with this new WS in an existing project.  I hae done a proof of concept and ironed out java issues already.

Comment: So is your code in a DLL? In that case the app.config from the app that starts needs the WCF configuration.

Comment: You mean I need to put this app.config in my console app as well?  Will get back in a sec.

Comment: copy and Paste to the rescue.  Thanks Maurice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so others can see the solution and not have to spit through the comments.

So is your code in a DLL? In that case the app.config from the app that starts needs the WCF configuration.